# Базовый конструктор с передачей параметров

Tags: c#

Есть ли какой-то другой способ вызова базового конструктора с передачей параметров? У меня в производном классе всего 2 поля, но мне надо опять переписывать все поля базового. Геморрой...

```
class SpecialTourPackage : TourPackage
{
    private int discount;
    private int peopleNumberForDiscount;

    public SpecialTourPackage(string travelType, int travelDuration, int priceForOnePerson, int groupCapacity, int discount, int peopleNumberForDiscount) : base
                             (travelType, travelDuration, priceForOnePerson, groupCapacity)
    {
        this.discount = discount;
        this.peopleNumberForDiscount = peopleNumberForDiscount;
    }
}
```

Comment: другой в смысле какой? Чтобы не передавать параметры?

Comment: для понимания, производный класс не `замещает`, а `расширяет` базовый класс. То есть если у вас в базовом 5 полей, а в производном ещё 2, то считай у вас в производном 7 полей.

Comment: @tym32167 Я знаю что в производном классе будет полей = полей в базовом + полей в производном. Что если у меня в базовом полей к примеру 20. И вот мне понадобился производный всего с двумя полями. Для производного также нужен конструктор куда будут передаваться аргументы для всех полей. И вот нет ли способа, чтобы я мог обозначить только новые аргументы для 2 новых полей, но не дублировать базовый конструктор. Но при этом при создании объекта вызывался и базовый и новый конструктор. Иначе это будет ой какая большая строчка с аргументами. А потом я еще сделаю производный от производного. И все.

Comment: @FreezeMatic значения по умолчанию при вызове базового конструктора? не? `0` например вместо переменной, или какую другую константу можно использовать.

Comment: Если базовый класс обязательно требует 5 параметров в конструкторе, то никак.

Comment: @aepot В том то и дело. При создании объекта нужно сразу все поля обозначить. Но никами-то дефолтными значениями.

Comment: @tym32167 Очень печально. Авто свойства они придумали, а авто конструктор с параметрами нет))) Зараза... (С) Ведьмак. Может Visual Studio умеет сама создавать конструктор с параметрами для всех полей? сокращение ctor я знаю, не предлагать. Оно лишь шаблон конструктора пишет(

Comment: Как бы это выглядело? Вот вы сделали производный класс, создаете экземпляр, передаёте в него 2 параметра, откуда возьмутся значения для остальных пяти параметров для базового класса?

Comment: @tym32167 Он об этом еще не задумывался.

Comment: @Igor никогда не поздно начать задумываться :)

Comment: @tym32167 А кто сказал что я не буду при создании экземпляра передавать аргументы для всех полей. Я не хочу заниматься тавтологией, дублируя в конструкторе производного класса еще раз параметры базового. Да хоть так к примеру. public SpecialTourPackage(int discount, int peopleNumberForDiscount) : use base ctor

Comment: @tym32167 но при создании передам все аргументы

Comment: для вот такого кода `public SpecialTourPackage(int discount, int peopleNumberForDiscount) : use base ctor` - компилятору придется переписать этот метод на 7 параметров и переписать вызов базового конструктора. Таких фокусов компилятор делать не умеет. Если прямо сильно хотите в это погрузиться, то надо смотреть в сторону кодогенераторов или AOP или порождающих паттернов (но имхо оно того не стоит). Сам компилятор C# ничего подобного не делает.

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен. Не стоит. Надеялся найти сахар.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно есть:

```
public SpecialTourPackage(int discount, int peopleNumberForDiscount) : base("", 0, 0, 0)
{
  ...
```

Comment: Ну или конструктор без параметров?

Comment: Если бы мне нужны были значения по умолчанию, то есть еще проще.

`public SpecialTourPackage(int discount, int peopleNumberForDiscount) : base()`

`public TourPackage()`

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите упростить код создания множества объектов класса `SpecialTourPackage`, у которых значения параметров для базового класса будут одинаковыми. Если это так, предлагаю обернуть все параметры базового класса в отдельный класс `TourPackageParams` и передавать их в конструктор. Получится примерно так:

```
class SpecialTourPackage : TourPackage
{
    private int discount;
    private int peopleNumberForDiscount;

    public SpecialTourPackage(TourPackageParams tourPackageParams, int discount, int peopleNumberForDiscount) : base(tourPackageParams)
    {
        this.discount = discount;
        this.peopleNumberForDiscount = peopleNumberForDiscount;
    }
}

class TourPackage
{
    private string travelType;
    private int travelDuration;
    private int priceForOnePerson;
    private int groupCapacity;

    public TourPackage(TourPackageParams tourPackageParams)
    {
        travelType = tourPackageParams.TravelType;
        travelDuration = tourPackageParams.TravelDuration;
        priceForOnePerson = tourPackageParams.PriceForOnePerson;
        groupCapacity = tourPackageParams.GroupCapacity;
    }
}

public class TourPackageParams
{
    public string TravelType { get; }
    public int TravelDuration { get; }
    public int PriceForOnePerson { get; }
    public int GroupCapacity { get; }

    public TourPackageParams(string travelType, int travelDuration, int priceForOnePerson, int groupCapacity)
    {
        TravelType = travelType;
        TravelDuration = travelDuration;
        PriceForOnePerson = priceForOnePerson;
        GroupCapacity = groupCapacity;
    }
}
```

И использование:

```
var tourPackageParams = new TourPackageParams("travelType", 1, 2, 3);

var specialTourPackage1 = new SpecialTourPackage(tourPackageParams, 1, 2);
var specialTourPackage2 = new SpecialTourPackage(tourPackageParams, 3, 4);
var specialTourPackage3 = new SpecialTourPackage(tourPackageParams, 5, 6);
```